# Excel VBA Unlocking cells to run a macro then locking again

Tags: vba, excel

Certain cells in my workbook are locked which unfortunately prevents a macro from running. So, I modified the macros located here http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/excel-vba-range-lockunlock-specific-cells/ to unlock the sheet, run a macro and then relock. I just wanted to post a solution.

```
Sub sumit2()
  'Unlocks cells A1:C5
 Dim mainworkBook As Workbook

 Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

   ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xx"


   mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5").Locked = False

  Call FillCell

  End Sub
Sub FillCell()

  Dim mainworkBook As Workbook

  Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

  mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5").Value = "Locked"

Call sumit
End Sub
Sub sumit()
'Protects cells A1:C5
  Dim mainworkBook As Workbook

  Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xx"


   mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C5").Locked = True

   ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xx"


 End Sub
```

Comment: Was there any question here or just a solution for reference ?

Comment: You may want to move that to [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/topics), since it is not a question. Also, you may want to protect the sheet with `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`, then macros can change stuff without unprotecting first. Saves a lot of Unprotect/Protect code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "Q&A" - this could be moved to Documentation, or asked in the more typical "Q&A" format, as mentioned in [Self-Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).